# the bazel sync failed problem when using mediapipe

Tags: bazel

I use ubuntu on win10 (WSL)

bazel can't sync
I can't find out how to solve. Help please~~
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2Rf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem. See [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/242) or [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/113).

Quote:

> Currently, the plugin only supports Linux.
>
> We plan to support Mac in the near future, and in the longer term
>   Windows as well, but there are no fixed dates planned.